# Android folder not being created by eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

On my new computer I downloaded eclispe Luna (4.4.2). I tried to install android on it (by going to https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and installing all). It was installed, so I restarted eclipse and got the message:

> Could not find SDK folder

And no android folder got created in any of my drives (its a new computer so I searched in any directory)! I removed eclipse, downloaded it again and tried and the same happend. I uninstalled DDMS and reinstalled it and the same happend. I uninstalled it and opened eclipse as administrator and reinstalled it and the same happend... If I click on Window -> Android SDK Manager I get that message and nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? I am using the same workspace I used in my old computer that had worked fine with android (tough I used eclipse keplar, so when I opened the new workspace eclipse asked me to upgrage and I agreed).

Please don't tell me to move to Android Studio - my project in eclipse consists of many multiple sub projects and I really don't want to configure it a new (why the hell do we have Gradle?!)

Comment: `why the hell do we have Gradle?` Google it. And importing existing modules in studio is quite easy. It's good to make a switch to Gradle honestly. You won't know unless use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have only downloaded the plugin for eclipse. You also need to download the SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

Answer (score 0):

You should install [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) separately.
Here is the [link](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Setup-Eclipse-for-Android-App-Development/?ALLSTEPS) to the page that will show you to install eclipse, adt and sdk.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are on a windows computer, so in Eclipse do the following:

- **Window -> Preferences -> Android**
- In the Android tab, there is a field saying "**SDK Location**". You can click browse and find where the folder "**android-sdks**" has been downloaded in your computer.
- Set the path to that folder as "**SDK Location**"
- It should be working now.

Usually the **"android-sdks"** folder is found under: *C:\Users\< your-username >\android-sdks* if it was downloaded from the ADT pluggin: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: My problem is that I don't *have* "android-sdk" (not even in users or any dir)...